# Powerpoint - Open PPTM (macro enabled) File on Startup

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, macros, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a PowerPoint presentation with a macro. I would like PowerPoint to open on startup the following to files.

1. **Blank.pptm (My custom PPT file with macro)**
2. **Blank.pptx (Default PPT file)** (Optional)

(**Note**: I am **not** looking to open these files on **Windows Startup**, but PowerPoint startup.)

I put `Blank.pptm` file in the following folder, but it does not work.

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates
```

Is it possible? I am using PowerPoint 2016.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Word/Excel, PowerPoint doesn't have a way to let you auto-run macros at startup by putting a macro-containing file in a special location.

Instead, you must create an add-in and install it.

Add a new procedure to your existing PPTM:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
   ' Add your startup code here
   Msgbox "Hi!  I'm here!"
End Sub
```

Save the file as a normal PPTM, then save it as an add-in (PPA if it must be compatible with current PPT versions and versions prior to 2007; PPAM if 2007 and later is sufficient).

Go to the Options dialog, choose Add-ins then Manage:  PowerPoint Addins and in the add-ins dialog that appears, browse to and select the PPA/PPAM you just saved.  Any code in the Auto_Open subroutine will run when the add-in loads (and it'll load whenever PPT starts up until you remove it).